# Doing the dynamic library tutorial but I have LNK2019 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, lnk2019

The tutorial I'm doing is this one :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I have vs2010 and I'm compiling everything in debug in win32. I'm pretty sure I've followed every instruction step by step. I can even find the function automatically with vs2010, but I cannot build the main project (the dll is fine)

I get the same error as the guy in the comment, which is :

> 1>MyExecRefsDll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: static double __cdecl
>   MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Divide(double,double)"
>   (?Divide@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> 1>MyExecRefsDll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: static double __cdecl
>   MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double,double)"
>   (?Multiply@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z) referenced in function
>   _main
>
> 1>MyExecRefsDll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: static double __cdecl
>   MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double,double)"
>   (?Subtract@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z) referenced in function
>   _main
>
> 1>MyExecRefsDll.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: static double __cdecl
>   MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add(double,double)"
>   (?Add@MyMathFuncs@MathFuncs@@SANNN@Z) referenced in function _main

Thank you!

Comment: Did you add `MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS` to the preprocessor definitions for the dll (only)?

Comment: Yes, I only put it in the header MathFuncDll.h as the tutorial told me to, which is in the dll project. Is there any other place I have to put it as well?

Comment: You need to add this to the project settings (property page) for the dll project in Solution Explorer. Under the C/C++ settings there is a `Preprocessor Definitions` property. In that add `MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS`

Comment: BTW, only add that to the dll. Adding it to the application will cause similar linker errors.

Comment: Ok the fix was to add in the propertie page -> linker -> input -> additionnal dependencies... the path with the file containing the MathFuncsDll.lib

Comment: Yes. Your application would need to link to the import library for the dll.